# React-Chartjs-2 and Chartjs v3:Option Property

Tags: reactjs, chart.js

i whould like to start with react-chartjs-2. The first thing that i have seen on the offical website, v4 -> imigration to chart.js 3.

On that website there were some examples with the data, but none with options.

I wonder how to use the option property. I have seen some exampels for that version but only with data, i couldnt find an example with the option property.

So how can I use options.

Comment: https://react-chartjs-2.js.org/examples/vertical-bar-chart

Answer (score 0):

`react-chartjs-2` uses the `Chart.js` library, so you can also refer to the `Chart.js` [docs](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/options.html).

Below is an example of the `options` used on a `Line` chart:

```
const options = {
  responsive: true,
  plugins: {
    legend: {
      position: 'top',
    },
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'Chart.js Line Chart',
    },
  },
}
```

As mentioned in the docs above, there are multiple levels of context objects that can be used. For example, if you want to customize the tooltip values or formatting, you can use the `tooltip` context object:

```
const options = {
  responsive: true,
  plugins: {
    tooltip: {
      // your customization goes here
    },
  },
}
```

For information on what configuration settings are available for the `tooltip` or other options, see the [Configuration](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html) section of the docs.

I'd suggest reading through the `Chart.js` docs and also taking a look at the working examples that can be found in the [Samples](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/other-charts/combo-bar-line.html) section.